# Three cards in a row instead of all cards in one column

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using react with material UI,
I have 40 dynamic cards in an array and when I render them , I want to have 3 cards in a row and I get all the cards in one column.
I'm using this card:
https://codesandbox.io/s/r084q99q34

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe you can use Flexbox ? I had the same problem and I resolved it thanks to FlexBox trough material ui. Also, be sure to use a material core version superior or equal to 4. Hope it helps !

```
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import {
    Grid,
    Card,
    CardContent,
    Typography,
    CardHeader
} from '@material-ui/core/'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        padding: theme.spacing(2)
    }
}))

export default function AltCard() {
    const classes = useStyles()
    const data = [
        { quarter: 1, earnings: 13000 },
        { quarter: 2, earnings: 16500 },
        { quarter: 3, earnings: 14250 },
        { quarter: 4, earnings: 19000 }
    ]
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Grid
                container
                spacing={2}
                direction="row"
                justify="flex-start"
                alignItems="flex-start"
            >
                {data.map(elem => (
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3} key={data.indexOf(elem)}>
                        <Card>
                            <CardHeader
                                title={`quarter : ${elem.quarter}`}
                                subheader={`earnings : ${elem.earnings}`}
                            />
                            <CardContent>
                                <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                                    Hello World
                                </Typography>
                            </CardContent>
                        </Card>
                     </Grid>
                ))}
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [Grid](https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/) component for this, e.g.

```
<Grid container spacing={24}>
  <Grid item md={3}>
    <Demo />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item md={3}>
    <Demo />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item md={3}>
    <Demo />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/rzmz5jnom

Comment: I tried it.  
but I got 40 dynamic cards so how can I map the array and every "map" render 3 different cards EX:
LOOP NUM 1:
render arr[0],arr[1],arr[2]
LOOP NUM 2:
render arr[3],arr[4],arr[5]

Answer (score 6):

Material UI provides `GridList` and `GridListTile` components. That let you configure it pretty well.

Grid lets you define columns and cells. A `tile` takes up one slot and it keeps fitting them in columns and overflowing them automatically if required. You can read more in the official [documents](https://material-ui.com/api/grid-list/) and take a look at their [samples](https://material-ui.com/demos/grid-list/) for inspiration.

```
let nums = Array.from(Array(40).keys());

  render(
    <GridList cols={3}>
      {nums.map(n => {
        return (
          <GridListTile key={n}>
            <Demo key={n} num={n} />
          </GridListTile>
        );
      })}
    </GridList>,
    rootElement
  );
```

See a forked sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/5yjpp339w4

If for some reason the inbuilt components do not suit your needs or if grid still confuses you, do take a look at their interactive [layout examples](https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/)

Comment: Thank you , but It needs to be more specific : 
If every card got a Date (DD/MM/YYYY) , Is it possible to put on one row only the Cards who have the same date?

Comment: Grid system allows you to do so... just understand what makes 'a tile' / 'cell' / 'GridListItem'... you will have to then tailor it as per your requirements... you can group them as per your data and even change the items contained within, but you have to look at the component demos of MUI and its Layout guide

Comment: How can this be made dynamic? ie, I only want one element per row on a mobile device, and 3 elements per row on desktop