# How can I fix the columns of the dynamic card?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I make the card appear where there are 2 columns for the 1st card and then another 2 columns far the second card? So for, this is what it shows.

[image]

but I wanted it to look like this:
[image]

these are my codes for the styling:

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  media: {
    height: 300,
  },
}));
```

and these are my codes for the card:

```
<div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={12}
        direction="row"
        justify="flex-start"
        alignItems="center"
      >
        {data.map((elem) => (
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3} key={data.indexOf(elem)}>
            <Card>
              <CardHeader title={name} subheader={desc} />
              <CardMedia
                className={classes.media}
                image={img}
                title={name}
              />

            </Card>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </div>
```

Comment: you need to implement CSS for that or className accordingly.

Comment: @sushildlh i'll have to use display:flex for this right?

Comment: That is already mentioned in material UI. Looks for more properties material doc provide

Comment: check this link and implement in your application. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56769962/5305430 . For more info join me.

Comment: @sushildlh I tried this it and edited the above code and it's still not rendering with the right columns

Comment: will you share your GitHub repo?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the cards are stretched to full width, which prevents them from sharing the same flex-row.

There are lots of possible solutions to this. One could be to set a max-width on the cards so they don't fill the whole row. That way they would have space to sit besides each other like in your example.